# ¿Cómo obtener tabla temporal al ejecutar un código SQL mediante sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(400)='
INSERT INTO  #AA(ID)
SELECT ID FROM BB
'

DECLARE @CREATETABLE NVARCHAR(400)='
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#AA'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AA
 CREATE TABLE #AA
    (
       ID INT
    )
'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @CREATETABLE
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @QUERY
```

Necesito obtener la tabla `#AA` con un SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes al menos con tablas temporales. Una tabla tipo `#tabla` solo es visible desde la sesión en que fue creada, en tu ejemplo, la temporal se crea en el contexto del sp_ExecuteSql, por lo cual al salir de él, la tabla deja de existir. Que yo sepa la única forma de resolverlo es que el `CREATE` se haga afuera del scope de `sp_ExecuteSql`, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(400)='
INSERT INTO  #AA(ID)
SELECT 1
'

CREATE TABLE #AA (ID INT)

EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @QUERY 
SELECT * FROM #AA
```

**Nota**: Al menos en SQL Server

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el ejemplo para poder obtener la tabla temporal con datos :

DECLARE @QryParaLlenarTablaTemporal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

Set @QryParaLlenarTablaTemporal = ' INSERT INTO  ##A(ID)
                                    SELECT Id  FROM Requirement
                                  '

EXEC sp_executesql @QryParaLlenarTablaTemporal

SELECT * FROM ##A

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: DEVJ Te fue util la respuesta?

Comment: DEVJ Te fue util la respuesta?